# Android Data Binding: ObservableArrayMap and `error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to ...`

Tags: android, data-binding, observable, android-databinding

I'm implementing data binding for my Android app using `ObservableArrayMap` in my layout xml.

The map has a clearly defined types for its keys and values (e.g. `ObservableArrayMap<String, Integer>`, **BUT** I keep getting the error `error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Integer`.

The cause of the error is obvious: the generated ViewBinding Java file completely ignores the types of the type arguments of the map and declares the map as `android.databinding.ObservableArrayMap`. So, when accessing its values, it returns `Object` instead of `Integer`.

Why the hell it does that? I get that the types are erased during runtime, but come on, it must work, otherwise, what's the point of defining the maps type arguments in the code?

**What's even weirder**, the compiler does perform type checking: if you were to pass the argument of a wrong type to the `get()` method in the layout xml, you get an error.

Comment: Could you add MVCE? just the part how you declare it inside xml and the part where you wana use it (and version of databinding lib)... dirty solution I think about is to use `MyClass extends ObservableArrayMap<String, Integer>`

Comment: @Selvin take a look at my detailed question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638336/data-binding-observablefield-with-lambda-value-doesnt-compile